# Type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete error

Tags: c++, c, struct, scope

I'm trying to write a program that print information of a student 
but Code::Blocks says :

error : Type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete.
error : conflicting types for 'displayStudentInformation'
and this is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void displayStudentInformation(struct student stu);

struct student{
  int id;
  char *firstName;
  char *lastName;
  float gpa;
};

int main()
{
  struct student stu1;
  stu1.id = 101;
  stu1.firstName = "Ali";
  stu1.lastName = "Alavi";
  stu1.gpa = 18;

  displayStudentInformation(stu1);

  return 0;
}

void displayStudentInformation(struct student stu)
{
  printf("Student information :\n");
  printf("ID : %d",stu.id);
  printf("First Name : %s",stu.firstName);
  printf("Last Name :%s",stu.lastName);
  printf("GPA : %.2f",stu.gpa);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Swap declarations of `struct` and `displayStudentInformation`

Comment: means, put the declaration of `struct student` before the declaration of `displayStudentInformation()` function.

Comment: @Amin Ataee  Just compile the program as a C++ program.;)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It's not fundamental difference between C and C++ syntax but i don't like C++ .

Comment: @AminAtaee Nevertheless the program will compile as a C++ program.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Really? Why? can you explain it to me? i'm a beginner

Comment: @AminAtaee In C++ the declaration of the parameter void displayStudentInformation(struct student stu); introduces the elaborated type name struct student in the global scope.

Comment: In C++, you don't need to specify the keyword `struct` for parameters and variables.

Comment: Be away that `stu1.firstName = "Ali"` is assigning *pointers* and not contents of strings.  In C++, use the `std::string` type.  If you must use character pointers, you should have an array to contain the data.  Also use the `str*()` family of functions for character arrays.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews really? I learn it from my books And video courses .. it's a dynamic string

Comment: Purge your videos and books.  Use `std::string` for text (one or more characters).  Use character arrays in structures when you need fixed width fields.  Prefer not to use pointers unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the struct before the function prototype:

```
struct student {
  int id;
  char *firstName;
  char *lastName;
  float gpa;
};

void displayStudentInformation(struct student stu);
```

Now the struct is known and can be used in the function prototype.

Note that you can `typedef` the struct in order to not have to write `struct student` every time you want to declare a variable of type `student`:

```
typedef struct student {
  int id;
  char *firstName;
  char *lastName;
  float gpa;
} student;

void displayStudentInformation(student stu);
```

Since your question is also tagged with "c++" for some reason (?) I have to mention here that in C++, you don't need to `typedef` it. You can just use `student` instead of `struct student` even without the `typedef`.

If you are going to use C++ instead of C, then I should also mention that it's recommended to use `std::string` instead of `char*` for strings. Please note that C++ is a *very different* language compared to C. If your current goal or task is to learn C, then don't just compile your C code with a C++ compiler. Please use a C compiler. If you use a C++ compiler, you can (and probably will) end up with code that is valid C++ but not valid C.